# How can find numbers in para after comma with regex for using xml

Tags: regex, xslt

I am trying to find the numbers in p element after the comma. e.g. `11.112, 11A.112, 11.112f`
**Input**

```
<p>U.S. patent laws, no preemption of 1.2, trade secret protection by, 11.112, 11A.112, 11.112f</p>
```

Also I am try:
https://regex101.com/r/K0vMQH/3

Comment: Is it in PHP, JavaScript or something else?

Comment: @Alexander Mashin Sir, I am using XSLT analyze string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
  <xsl:template match="p">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of 
            select="analyze-string(., ',\s*([0-9]+[A-Z]*\.[0-9]+[A-Z]*)', 'i')//*:group[@nr = 1]"
            separator=", "/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

you get `<p>11.112, 11A.112, 11.112f</p>`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVruFNJ